# How to count the number of periods a student presents on a given days in Firebase real time database on Android?

Tags: android

here is a result of the code for com(R)020-09

[image]

I am trying to develop an android application for student attendance taker and I want to count the number of periods a student exists to calculate the percentage of his or her presence. but it doesn't return the correct values. Please help me I am a beginner.
here is the structure of my database structure
[image: database structure]

and here is the code that I have tried

```
public class student_attendance_sheet extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int count = 1, P = 1, A = 1;
    float average = (float) 0.0;
    TextView t;
    String avg, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
    String student_id;
    ArrayList dates = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference dbAttendance;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_attendance_sheet);

        t = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        listView =  findViewById(R.id.list);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        student_id = bundle.getString("sid");
        t.setText(student_id);

        dates.clear();
        dates.add("       Date          " + "p1  " + "p2  " + "p3  " + "p4   " + "p5   " + "p6  " );

        dbAttendance = ref.child("attendance");
        dbAttendance.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    p1 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p1").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    p2 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p2").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    p3 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p3").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    p4 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p4").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    p5 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p5").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    p6 = dsp.child(student_id).child("p6").getValue().toString().substring(0, 1);
                    dates.add(dsp.getKey() + "    " + p1 + "     " + p2 + "     " + p3 + "     " + p4 + "      " + p5 + "       " + p6 ); //add result into array list


                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dsp.child(student_id).child("p1").getValue().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (p1.equals("P") || p2.equals("P") || p3.equals("P") || p4.equals("P") || p5.equals("P") || p6.equals("P")) {

                        P++;
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (p1.equals("A") || p2.equals("A") || p3.equals("A") || p4.equals("A") || p5.equals("A") || p6.equals("A") ) {
                        A++;
                        count++;
                    }




                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(student_attendance_sheet.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, dates);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                try {

                    average = (float) ((P * 100) / count);
                    String avg = Float.toString(average);
                    t.setText("Your Attendance : " + avg + "%" + "total:"+count+" "+"P:"+P+ "Abs:"+A);
                    if (average >= 75)
                        t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    if (average < 75)
                        t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //list(dates, P, count, A);


                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dates.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void list(ArrayList studentlist, int P, int count, int A) {
        // Toast.makeText(this,NOP+TOC,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, studentlist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        try {

            average = (float) ((P * 100) / count);
            String avg = Float.toString(average);
            t.setText("Your Attendance : " + avg + "%" + "total:"+count+" "+"P:"+P+ "Abs:"+A);
            if (average >= 75)
                t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (average < 75)
                t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: can you add what it returns instead please

Comment: it counts the number of P, count and A incorrectly for a specific student so that the average is calculated wrongly. what i need is to count these values correctly.help me. i have edited tou can see the scrrenshot

Comment: try initializing A and P to equal 0 not 1

Comment: i have tried this, but it doesn't count correctly.

Comment: what did it return when you did so

Comment: it counts P to  3,    A to 1

Comment: sir, please help me with sample of code. i am very tiered with it.

Comment: Sorry i failed , i'll try again in shaa allah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the condition you are using to add p or a is getting called once because you are not itterating over the p's and a's
So you can just separate your condition to be

```
If(p1.equals(P)){
     P++
    }
```

And so on
Or you have to itterate over the id children which are p1 , p2 , p3 ...

Comment: Glad I could help , Thanks to Allah , anytime :)